# Unable to locate package ambari-server in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, hadoop

I'm trying to install ambari server in virtualbox ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.
I'm following this installation guide.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+2.0.1+from+Public+Repositories

In the step 2 i am getting this error 
Unable to locate package ambari-server.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** you have a 64-bit system follow the steps below. The packages are **NOT** available for 32-bit.

Download the `list` file for Ubunru 12.04 and place the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` via

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari.list http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu12/2.x/updates/2.0.1/ambari.list
```

After that

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambari-server
```

All packages are available [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/index.html#/ambari/ubuntu12/2.x/updates/2.0.2/pool/main/a), too.